# Excel Mac/OSX 2016, importing data without $ sign

Tags: excel, macos

[image: Excel Mac 2016]

I'm importing data from coinmarketcap in Excel. However I cannot perform any calculations without removing the dollar sign from the data first.

I have several sheets of data being imported every 5 mins then a mastersheet which should perform various calculations, stats etc.

Is it possible to automatically have the dollar sign removed from the imported data?

Is there anyway to automate this process?

Comment: import as money format, or create another column and store the converted value

Comment: Thanks but I cannot import as a currency. Basically I'm looking how to automate the process, I think the answer is with a macro.